# Receiving "Nullable object must have a value." exception in TFS Online API V1.0

Tags: azure-devops, tfs-workitem

I've been using code to add work items to Visual Studio Online with the v1.0 Preview 2 API for Work Item Tracking for over a month now, and it seems like something has broken my usage of the API now that it is no longer in preview. The same JSON sent before the update was operational. The data sent is:

```
[{"op":"add","path":"/fields/System.Title","value":"dev task"},{"op":"add","path":"/fields/System.IterationPath","value":"Valid Iteration Path"},{"op":"add","path":"/fields/Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Activity","value":"Development"},{"op":"add","path":"/relations/-","value":{"rel":"System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Reverse","url":"https://myurl.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workItems/2722","attributes":{"comments":"Added sub task"}}},{"op":"add","path":"/fields/System.AssignedTo","value":"Valid User"}]
```

And the response I'm receiving now is:

```
{"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"Nullable object must have a value.","typeName":"System.InvalidOperationException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089","typeKey":"InvalidOperationException","errorCode":0,"eventId":0}
```

Is there something new that's required that I'm just not aware of?